# Using threading to get tweets using Streaming API without getting rate-limited

Tags: java, multithreading, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I want to use threading to stream the tweets but I am getting rate-limited. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class AppThread {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
            Runnable worker = new App("Thread" + i);  
            executor.execute(worker);//calling execute method of   ExecutorService  
          }  
        executor.shutdown();  
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {   }  

        System.out.println("Finished all threads");  
}
```

In the following class, another class(not included) is called to fetch the tweets.

```
public class App implements Runnable {
private String threadName;
TwitterStream twitterStream = new     TwitterStreamFactory().getTwitterStreamInstance();
TwitterStreamWorker streamWorker = new TwitterStreamWorker();

public App(String name) {
    this.threadName = name;
}

public void appTwitter() {

    String[] queryParams = { "Delhi" };
    String[] queryLang = { "en" };
    FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
    FilterQuery query = filterQuery.getFilterQueryInstance(queryParams, queryLang);
    System.out.println("Query " + query);
    streamWorker.startStreamingWorker(twitterStream, query);
}

public void run() {

        System.out.println("Running thread " + threadName);
        appTwitter();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public void start() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I have also tried using newSingleThreadExecutor() but the problem remains the same.

Comment: If you get the same problem when using a single thread only, then I suspect your problem is not with threads. If it's not, then why don't you simplify the program and try doing the same without the threads whatsoever?

Comment: When I am not using threads, there isn't any problem.  And no problem also with a single thread.

Comment: I want to use multi threading to speed up the process.

Comment: In the question you wrote: "I have also tried using newSingleThreadExecutor() but the problem remains the same.", which I thought meant "the same problem happens when I use a single thread".